# What does @ mean in a match statement?

Tags: rust, rotor

I've started to study [the rotor library](https://github.com/tailhook/rotor/) and I've [found the expression](https://github.com/tailhook/rotor/blob/55c678afea1dc5bc9ccc7cb4e4b1e4035c08ae47/examples/tcp_echo_server.rs#L61):

```
me @ Echo::Server(..) => me.accept(),
```

What does this mean and how do I use the `@` operator? My guess is that it is something like a cast operation, but the Rust book's [section about casting](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/casting-between-types.html) doesn't mention it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [syntax index in the Rust Book](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/syntax-index.html) to look up bits of syntax.  In this case, it's a [pattern binding](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/patterns.html#bindings), used to bind a specific part of a pattern to a variable.

Here, it's being used to bind the entire value to `me` if and only if it is an `Echo::Server` variant.